# Explanation of Barycentric coordinates

Tags: affine-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Let $ABC$ be a triangle in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ (in other words, the points $A,B,C$ are affinely independent). Let $AA_1, BB_1, CC_1$ be the medians of this triangle meeting at the point $M$. Find the barycentric coordinates of $M,A_1,B_1,C_1$ with respect to $A,B,C$.

I think for barycentric coordinates, we set $A=(1,0,0),B=(0,1,0), C=(0,0,1)$. Yet I have no idea why $M=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$. Is there any explanation?

Comment: are you familiar/comfortable with the idea of putting weights of 1 at those points, and hence the centroid has weight 1/3, 1/3, 1/3?

Comment: @Calvin Lin Not very familiar. More elaboration please. Thank you!

Comment: @Endpoints It helped if you added more context, like how were barycentric coordinates introduced to you, and what properties you know and are allowed to use. For examp;le, how did (or would) you prove the formula for the midpoint of a segment in barycentric coordinates.

Comment: You can see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4017458

Answer (score 1):

First, Euclidean geometry tells us that $$\overrightarrow{AM}=2\overrightarrow{MA_1},\overrightarrow{BM}=2\overrightarrow{MB_1},\overrightarrow{CM}=2\overrightarrow{MC_1}. \quad(*)$$
Let $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ be vectors representing $A,B,C$, and let $\vec{m}=\frac{1}{3}(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})$ then you can verify $(*)$ by plugging the vectors. There is a unique point $M$ satisfying $(*)$, so $M=\vec{m}$.