Why Do the Medians of a Triangle Intersect at a Single Point?
I was reading a fascinating book called Measurement by Paul Lockhart. It had a beautiful introduction with this problem.
I came up with a proof for this problem, but I’m not entirely confident that it’s flawless. I’d love to share my proof with you and get your thoughts on any possible weaknesses. Also, the book discusses symmetry, but I’m not sure I fully grasp the role it plays in this context. Is there a more elegant or insightful proof that uses symmetry or perhaps approaches it differently?
If you have a particularly beautiful proof for why the medians meet at one point, I'd love to hear it.
Here’s my proof:

To start, as suggested in the book, I connected the midpoints of the triangle's sides. This creates parallelograms: A'BC'B', A'C'AB', and CA'C'B' (Midpoint Theorm), which will come in handy later. The intersection of the medians seems to form a "triangle" within these parallelograms (although I initially assumed it was a triangle rather than a single point, which I will later show to be an infinitely small triangle). The only region shared by all these parallelograms is the triangle A'B'C', so the intersection must lie within this triangle.

Next, when the medians are drawn, points E, F, and D become the midpoints of the sides. Why is this the case? Because in a parallelogram, the diagonals bisect each other.

Now, we can focus on the triangle A'B'C', which contains this supposed intersection "triangle," and repeat the process by connecting its midpoints E, F, and D just as before.

We can continue this process infinitely, each time getting a smaller triangle that contains the intersection. As we keep repeating, the "triangle" formed by the intersection becomes an infinitely small area. Even if you suggest that the intersection is a very tiny triangle, I could still find a smaller triangle that would contain it. This means the intersection is ultimately contained within an infinitely small region, showing that all the medians meet at a single point.

So what is your question about the proof?

Note that the theorem holds in affine spaces over any field (well, at least fields where 2 and 3 are invertible).

I'm sorry. I had mistakenly erased the first part of the question before posting. I readded it.

your proof more or less works, but to make it fully rigorous you have to do the part of this infinitely continued triangles in a calculus/analysis sort of language. Besides, you also need to do a bit more on this chained inclusions - you happened to precisely draw three medians, so you know the intersections is a point.
Draw a scenario where the three cevians are not concurrent and you might suddenly find the assertion about the inclusion a bit more involved than just saying it's obvious.

@dezdichado Thank You. This is really helpful. Fun fact: I didn’t actually draw exactly three medians. I repeated the same process I used in the third image about 20 times. When I drew it, I never made those three lines connect. However, the gap is really small, and since the image is a PNG, you can't actually see it. But I agree with what you said—it would have been more effective to prove it visually by contradiction, although I did include that approach in my written proof. Thanks again for the suggestion!

You can see  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4017458.

See Ceva's Theorem.

Pick any two points, say $A$ and $C$, and construct $A'$ and $C'$ as the midpoints of $BC$ and $AB$. Then $AC||A'C'$ by similar  triangles.
Let $M$ be the point where $AA'$  intersects $CC'$. Then $\triangle ACM\sim \triangle A'C'M$.
Therefore $2|A'M|=|AM|$ because $2|A'C'|=|AC|$, so the ratio is $2:1$.
Repeating the process for two different points also creates a $2:1$ ratio, so the lines must be concurrent.

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I think this could work:
Let's start from the triangle $\triangle \text{ABC}$, with $\text{A'}, \text{B'}$ and $\text{C'}$ midpoints of $\text{BC}, \text{AC}$ and $\text{AB}$ respectively.

Now, we can connect $\text{B}$ with $\text{B'}$ and $\text{C}$ with $\text{C'}$. Let's call $\text{M}$ the intersection between the two segments. Then we can connect $\text{A}$ with $\text{M}$ and $\text{M}$ with $\text{A'}$.

If we can show that the angle $\angle{\text{AMA'}}$ is flat, we're done. Since $\text{B'C'}$ is half the lenght of $\text{BC}$, $\text{A'C'}$ is half the lenght of $\text{AC}$ and $\text{A'B'}$ is half the lenght of $\text{AB}$, $\triangle \text{A'B'C'}$ and $\triangle \text{ABC}$ are similar.
So $\angle{\text{AMA'}}$ and $\angle{\text{A'MD}}$ are the same and therefore $\angle{\text{AMA'}}$ is flat.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
